# Is it possible to mimic the " frame.plot=F" from Plot in base R graphics with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to reproduce the `frame.plot=F` function of the base R plot in ggplot2. Do you know if there's a function or a theme available that can mimic something like this:
[image: 1]]

Thanks and happy new year!

Comment: maybe `theme_classic()` is what you are looking for ?

Comment: no... theme_classic doesn't do it...

Comment: What specifically are you trying to mimic, having just lines along the axes but not a border around the plotting area?

Comment: Just the above plot in ggplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something quite similar can be accomplished using the `lemon` package. Here is a sample plot made with the following code:

```
library(lemon)    

theme_classic() +
coord_capped_cart(bottom = "both",
                left = "both")
```

[image: Sample plot capped cart]

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. Is library limon compatible with ggplot?

Comment: Yes. You can build the plot using ggplot and just add the code I posted.